# Saving a Kendo datasource using jStorage

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, jstorage

I'm adding and removing data to a Kendo dataSource. I wish to save it localStorage, and be able to read it again from localStorage.

Here I've attempted to use jStorage for the saving and loading of data.

How it's loaded:

```
if ($.jStorage.get('favoritter') != null) {
    var datakilde_favoritter = $.jStorage.get('favoritter');
} else {
    var data = [
        {id: 5, name: "LINK ONE", url: "http://www.linkone.com" }
    ];
    var datakilde_favoritter = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: data,
        sort: { field: "name", dir: "asc" }
    });
}
```

How it's saved:

```
$.jStorage.set('favoritter', datakilde_favoritter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your DataSource as:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read   : function (op) {
            var data = $.jStorage.get('favoritter');
            if (!data) {
                data = [
                    {id: 5, name: "LINK ONE", url: "http://www.linkone.com" }
                ];
            }
            op.success(data);
        },
        update : function (op) {
            $.jStorage.set("favoritter", ds.data());
            op.success(op.data);
        },
        destroy: function (op) {
            console.log("destroy", ds.data());
            $.jStorage.set("favoritter", ds.data());
            op.success(op.data);
        },
        create : function (op) {
            $.jStorage.set("favoritter", ds.data());
            op.success(op.data);
        }
    },
    sort     : { field: "name", dir: "asc" },
    pageSize : 10,
    schema   : {
        model: {
            id    : "id",
            fields: {
                id  : { type: 'number' },
                name: { type: 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You might consider removing `create` and `destroy` if not needed.

And your grid would be something like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    editable  : "popup",
    pageable  : true,
    toolbar   : ["create"],
    columns   : [
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], width: 100 },
        { field: "id", width: 90, title: "#" },
        { field: "name", width: 90, title: "URL Name" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Basically when updating you need to invoke `op.success` with the data returned from the server. In your case since it is the browser itself, you don't need just to return the original data.